# How to do annotation in map with onetomany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate

Actually I need to do annotation for this map tag.kindly help me to do.I'm new to this annotation.

In my xml file,

```xml
<map name="Report" table="ABC_TABLE" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="ORIGINAL_GUID"/>
      <map-key column="REPORT_GUID" type="string"/>
      <one-to-many class="com.reporting.ReportingPO"/>
</map>
```

And in my Pojo class I need to give annotation

```
//annotations    
private Map<String, ReportingPO> Reporting = new HashMap<String, ReportingPO>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="<name_of_join_table>")
@MapKeyColumn(name="<name_of_map_key_in_table>")
@OneToMany(cascade = all-delete-orphan)// specify your annotation
private Map<String, ReportingPO> Reporting
```

The above generates a join table with three fields:

1.) One for the `mapping id`

2.) One for the `key`

3.) One for the `value`.

refer [here](http://hwellmann.blogspot.in/2010/07/jpa-20-mapping-map.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
private User user;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following code

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
private Student student;
```